# Desktop Backup Software with Google Cloud Storage

Tags: backup

I am looking for a desktop Backup-Software that works with `Google Cloud Storage`.
Meaning monitoring file changes in my computer and backup the files in `Google Cloud Storage`.

Comment: Do you want to backup your computer TO Google Cloud Storage, or backup your Google Cloud Storage to something else?

Comment: my computer to Google Cloud Storage.

Comment: Then edit your question saying that...

Comment: This question doesn't have enough information to be answerable. What operating system does your computer run? Approximately what data volume do you have? Do you want a simple synchronization or do you want to store incremental backups? Do you need to be able to restore old versions of individual files or just a global restore? Please read our [tips on asking questions](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you meant Desktop Software that would backup the drives on your computer to an online service like Google Cloud Storage, then this should work,

**[CloudBerry BackUp](http://www.cloudberrylab.com/google-cloud-backup-desktop.aspx)** (Desktop Backup, $29.99)

CloudBerry Backup transfers data to Google Cloud Storage and restores it in minutes. CloudBerry Backup connects directly to Google Cloud account and securely transfers backup files and folders to the cloud, serving as a transport between your Windows end-point and your Google Cloud account. To start working with Google Cloud Storage simply connect your Google Cloud account to CloudBerry Backup. The software comes with an easy to use Backup Wizard that will guide you through the backup plan setup process.
[image: CloudBerry Welcome Wizard]

Comment: I've seen that CloudBerry does not support encryption for Google Drive, although it encrypts for Amazon storage. Not sure about Google Cloud Storage, though.